# IE - Access denied to angular.js file because of XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xdomainrequest

I have problem with Internet Explorer. I made a simple application in AngularJS, in Mozilla everything works file, but in IE I have problem like this:

```
Error: Access is denied.

at Anonymous function (file:[path]/angular%20app%20view%202/resources/angular.js:9766:7)
at sendReq (file:[path]/angular%20app%20view%202/resources/angular.js:9628:9)
at serverRequest (file:[path]/angular%20app%20view%202/resources/angular.js:9344:9)
at processQueue (file:[path]/angular%20app%20view%202/resources/angular.js:13189:11)
at Anonymous function (file:[path]/angular%20app%20view%202/resources/angular.js:13205:27)
at Scope.prototype.$eval (file:[path]/GDP
```

Piece of my HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script src="resources/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body ng-app [...]
```

Piece of angular.js file:

```
function createXhr() {
    return new window.XMLHttpRequest();
}
[...]
line 9766 -> xhr.open(method, url, true);
```

I open my site locally from a file.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you!